# How can I implement two way binding with angular2

Tags: angular

I'm completely new to angular 2, I am trying to bind the data from the list to the input field, I have a div and inside the div I have a ul and one input field, what Im trying to do is to insert bind the input with the data when I click on each name listed, also I want to have only two input fields (not two fields for each listed name as it is now)

[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E64I.png)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
            import {MainService} from './main.service'

            @Component({
              selector: 'my-app',
              template:`
                <div  *ngFor="let user of data" (click)="message(user.name, user.number)">
                    <ul>
                        <li>{{user.name}}</li>
                    </ul>

                    Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name"><br><br>
                    number: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.number">
                </div>

              `,
              providers: [MainService]
            })
            export class AppComponent {
                data: any[];
                constructor(private mainservice: MainService){

                }
                ngOnInit(){
                    console.log("Test")
                    this.getUsers()
                }
                getUsers(){

                    this.mainservice.getUsers().subscribe(
                        data => {
                            console.log(data)
                            this.data = data;
                            },
                        error => {
                            console.log(error)

                        }
                        )
                }
                message(name, num){
                    console.log(name + " " + num)
                }

             }
```

Comment: is show/hide  fine?

Comment: Yes its fine, im guessing it should use ngIf?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. I think you just had your HTML wrong.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <div  *ngFor="let user of data" (click)="EditUser(user)">
        <ul>
            <li>{{user.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    Name: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.name">
    <br /> <br />
    Number: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.num">
  `,
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, MainService]
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/x1leEPz4w2rzV1LQyVkB?p=preview

Comment: Thank you this really fixed my issue, I realize my mistake